# how use awk for put at the begin the last value by record field?

Tags: awk

Im triying to get all record an put at begin the last value per record but I dont know how

This is my input

```
grey;5
grey;6
grey;3
blue:2
blue;1
blue;0
red;5
red;7
red;2
```

this is my expected output

```
grey;3
grey;5
grey;6
grey;3
blue;0
blue:2
blue;1
blue;0
red;2
red;5
red;7
red;2
```

I use this command but not works

```
 awk -F\; '{a[$1]=$0} $0; END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file
```

what could I do

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter, you can do something like this:

```
awk -F\; '{a[$1]=a[$1]"-"$0} END{for(i in a){x=a[i]; match(x, /[^ -]*$/, b); x=b[0]""x; gsub(/-/,"\n", x); print x} }' File

red;2
red;5
red;7
red;2
grey;3
grey;5
grey;6
grey;3
blue;0
blue;2
blue;1
blue;0
```

Note : In your sample values, I assume you meant `blue;2` instead of `blue:2`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using GNU awk since the data had multiple delimiters but if you fix the delimiters in the file, you can use any awk and `-F:`, for example:

```
$ awk -F"[;:]" '       # set the delimiter
$1!=p && NR>1 {        # then the $1 changes (excluding the start)
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)  # loop thru all stored entries starting and ending with last
        print a[j]     # and output them
    i=0                # reset array index
}
{
    p=$1               # previous key for detecting the change
    a[0]=a[++i]=$0     # store the last record to array 0 and i
}
END {                  # in the end flush the buffer
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
        print a[j]
}' file
grey;3
grey;5
grey;6
grey;3
blue;0
blue:2
blue;1
blue;0
red;2
red;5
red;7
red;2
```